# how to use Mongoose populate on subdocument on the same model?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

This is my product model.

```
const featureHeaderSchema = new Schema({
    header: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});
const featureSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    parentHeader: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "product.featureHeaders" }, // not sure if this is correct
    parentFeature: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "product.features" },  // not sure if this is correct
});
const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        thumbnail: String,
        description: String,
        manufacture: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
        featureHeaders: {
            type: [featureHeaderSchema],
        },
        features: {
            type: [featureSchema],
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
const productModel = mongoose.model("product", productSchema);
```

I wanted to find a product by its id and get parentHeader's title and parentFeature's title with populate.

I tried to get product info by product ID and populate on parentHeader and parentFeature so I could have their titles on my output.

I tried this query:

```
const output = await productModel
    .findById(newProduct._id)
    .populate("features.parentFeature")
    .exec();
```

but I get this error: **MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "product.features".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, what your trying to do isn't possible with `populate`. That's because the `ref` property in the schema declaration is for referencing a model, not a path. It's used to tell mongoose which model you want to use to perform the `$lookup` and mongoose expects that model to correspond to a collection in your database.

Secondly, you are using subdocuments in your `productSchema` for the `featureHeaders` and `features` arrays so `populate` won't work for you regardless.

Thankfully you can fix this and get `populate` working for you. Although your naming convention and use case is a little confusing, hopefully this will help to explain how it's done:

1. `FeatureHeader` and `Feature` need to have their own collection, not be subdocuments so you need to create models for them.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const featureHeaderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    header: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});
// You need create the FeatureHeader model
const FeatureHeader = mongoose.model("FeatureHeader", featureHeaderSchema);

const featureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    parentHeader: { 
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
       ref: "FeatureHeader" //< Reference the FeatureHeader model
    }, 
    parentFeature: { 
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
       ref: "Feature" //< You can reference the same model (i.e self)
    }
});
// You need create the Feature model
const Feature = mongoose.model("Feature", featureSchema);

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   thumbnail: String,
   description: String,
   manufacture: { 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: "User" //< Capitalise the model name
   },
   featureHeaders: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "FeatureHeader", //< Reference the FeatureHeader model
   }],
   features: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Feature", //< Reference the Feature model
   }],
},
{ timestamps: true });
// You need create the Feature model
const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

2. `FeatureHeader` and `Feature` need to be saved separately in their own collection in order to be referenced .

```js
const newFeatureOne = await Feature.create({
   title: 'Marvel',
});

const newFeatureHeader = await FeatureHeader.create({
   header: 'Superhero'
});

const newFeatureTwo = await Feature.create({
   title: 'Repulsor Beams',
   parentHeader: newFeatureHeader._id,
   parentFeature: newFeatureOne._id
});

const newProduct = await Product.create({
   title: 'Repulsor Beams',
   //...
   //... 
   featureHeaders: [newFeatureHeader._id],
   features: [newFeatureTwo._id],
});
```

3. Now you can call `populate` to replace the `ObjectId` with their corresponding document:

```js
const id = req.body.id; //< Could be req.params.id or however you get the id

const product = await Product.findById(id)
   .populate("featureHeaders")
   .populate("features");
```

**Note**: Depending on your design and how the models are scoped you may need to specify the `path` and/or the `model` properties of the `populate` options object like so:

```js
const id = req.body.id; //< Could be req.params.id or however you get the id

const product = await Product.findById(id)
   .populate({path: "featureHeaders", model: "FeatureHeader"})
   .populate({path: "features", model: "Feature"});
```

Hopefully all of that makes sense and if you have any questions then please ask in the comments.

Comment: By selecting each feature of the product, I may display different low-level features to the user. Therefore, I created a record in the database for each feature. I wasn't sure if I could use such a method in Mongoose or not. Now considering that I have to increase the number of my collections. I think that I can choose one of these 3 paths.

1. Continue the same path and make the desired output using JavaScript functions
2. Increase collections as you instructed
3. Using SQL databases.

What path do you suggest?

Comment: SQL is better for relational data as all RDBM are designated for that use case but for flexibility NoSQL databases such as MongoDB are easier to work with. It looks like from your schema that not all field are required so that would lean towards mongodb and more collections. If you research [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/) in mongodb you can do a lot of your complex logic in the database to avoid lots of javascript functions.